# Namespace Orginization and Conventions

Tags: c#, json, conventions, stackexchange-api

So I have a little bit of a problem. I working on a project in C# using The StackOveflow API. You can send it a request like so:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/rep/126196/2010-01-01/2010-03-13
```

And get back something like this JSON response:

```
[{"PostUrl":"1167342",
  "PostTitle":"Are ref and out in C# the same a pointers in C++?",
  "Rep":10},
 {"PostUrl":"1290595",
  "PostTitle":"Where can I find a good tutorial on bubbling?",
  "Rep":10}
 ...
```

So my problem is that I have some methods like `GetJsonResponse()` which return the above JSON and `SaveTempFile()` which saves that JSON response to a temporary file for later use. I not sure if I should create a class for them, or what namespace to put them under. Right now my current namespace hierarchy is like so: `StackOverflow.Api.Json`. So how should I organize these methods/classes/namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you have a class representing a site, which knows about the URLs involved etc, then a method such as `GetReputationChanges(int userId, DateTime from, DateTime to)`. That can return you a list of posts (where a post is another class).

All of this should be in the same namespace, IMO.

I have some of this already for my [Reputation Tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx) - I don't know to what extent this has already been built into the [API that Kevin has built](http://code.google.com/p/stackexchange-api/). You're aware that they're working on an *official* API though, right?

Comment: I should really read the blog before I start a new project. I didn't know Kevin was building an API for .NET. Oh, well.